# What does OBDII fault code P0120 really mean?

Tags: electrical, obd-ii, sensor, renault, kangoo

What does OBDII fault code P0120 mean? The device said: "TPS/Pedal Position Sensor A Circuit Malfunction". The problem is that TPS stands for: "Throttle-body Position Sensor, which sits under the bonnet on the throttle-body. The Pedal Position Sensor, on the other hand, is located on the accelerator pedal. I assume that one of the two sensors is faulty, but which one? Or could it be that both are faulty?

Besides the "electric fault" warning icon frequently coming on (it goes away when I restart the engine), the problematic vehicle has recently become hard to start in the mornings, and has had two recent incidents of uncontrolled acceleration.

It should probably be mentioned that the vehicle in question is a Renault Kangoo.

Answer (score 1):

TPS stands for throttle position sensor. In drive by wire there are two throttle position sensors. One is a throttle body position sensor and the other is a pedal position sensor. The P0120 fault codes refers to the pedal position TPS.

Comment: +1. Thx. Do you know we’re the TPS/pedal position sensor is located? Is it on the throttle body, or on the accelerator pedal?

Comment: It's at the accelerator pedal. A mechanic would not replace it based on a code itself. He would first diagnose to confirm it's faulty. There are many things that can cause a code to appear. Also there may be some calibration involved with sensor replacement.

Comment: Are you aware of a code for a faulty throttle body sensor?

Comment: Actually there are two throttle position sensors in drive by wire cars, sensor A and B both located in the throttle body.  The pedal also has two sensors, the idea is that A travels one way and B does the inverse for diagnosis.  The codes for accelerator pedal problems are different than this one.  They should datalog throttle position voltages for each sensor and make sure A and B are direct inverses of each other to determine if the sensor (possibly wiring) is bad.